# factory_girl and sprintf

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

first of all, i am quite new to Ruby, although i have a strong background in Java (not helping here :). I created my first Rails application and i am using FactoryGirl. I came across something weird (for me) and i cannot figure out why it is behaving like this.

Using sprintf within a factory (see the last test) raises the following error :

```
Failures:
  1) Test raises an ArgumentError
     Failure/Error: sprintf('Product %05d', n)
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
     # ./spec/models/fg_spec.rb:6:in `fff'
     # ./spec/models/fg_spec.rb:31:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/fg_spec.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the full spec demonstrating this behavior:

```
def fff(n)
    sprintf('WWW Product %05d', n)
end

b1 = proc { |n| fff(n) }
b2 = proc { |n| sprintf('WWW Product %05d', n) }

FactoryGirl.define do

    factory :product1, :class => Product do
        sequence(:name) { |n| 'Product %05d' % "#{n}" }
    end

    factory :product2, :class => Product do
        sequence(:name) { |n| sprintf('WWW Product %05d', n) }
    end

    factory :product3, :class => Product do
        sequence(:name, 1, &b1)
    end

    factory :product4, :class => Product do
        sequence(:name, 1, &b2)
    end

    factory :product5, :class => Product do
        sequence(:name) { |n| fff(n) }
    end

end

describe Test do

    it "works with %" do
        p = Factory.create(:product1)
        puts p.inspect
    end

    it "does not work with sprintf" do
        expect { Factory.create(:product2) }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
    end

    it "works with a block with a function" do
        p = Factory.create(:product3)
        puts p.inspect
    end

    it "works with a block with sprintf" do
        p = Factory.create(:product4)
        puts p.inspect
    end

    it "does not work with a function with sprintf" do
        expect { Factory.create(:product5) }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
    end

end
```

Of course i could use the % notation but i am really curious about this.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to access sprintf using its full namespace:

```
b2 = proc { |n| Kernel.sprintf('WWW Product %05d', n) }
```

This is because the code in question is being called from within a different context where sprintf is undefined.

Comment: thanks, that works ; I assumed that Kernel was always in scope... like java.lang.* which does not need to be imported in Java ; weird :)